# The annoying 'Network error while fetching' while bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gitlab

I'm trying to install the newest version of gitlab. When I try

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql was --verbose
```

It always shows an error `Network error while fetching`, and re-fetches all the packages again when I retry, then the error appears again because my network is not stable. How to tell the bundler not to fetch packages already fetched?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the bundle install `--retry` option:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --retry 4 --deployment --without development test mysql was --verbose
```

This will retry failed network requests 4 times. From the [Bundler Documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_install.html):

> --retry: Retry network and git requests that have failed.

Note: if it complains about `Unknown switches '--retry'`, then your `bundler` version is very old. update it with:

```
gem update bundler
```

and then try again.

Comment: Bundler 1.6.4 was the culprit for me. Updated to 1.6.5 with `gem update bundler` and is fixed : )